# Field format error: Secure Token Not found

Tags: paypal, checkout

This does not make sense.

I am using Paypal Payments Advance, using the hosted checkout pages.

I am following this in setting it up:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

I use cURL to grab a Secure Token (RESULT=0, RESPMSG=Approved, I get back SECURETOKEN AND SECURETOKENID as expected)

I Use my paypal manager login, and user (user I created, with API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS).  I verify PARTNER, VENDOR, USER, PWD are all correct, TRXTYPE = S, CREATESECURETOKEN = Y, and pass a 36 length random hash.  Transaction Process Mode is Test.

When I go to test (cURL URL grabbing secure token from https:// pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com) and then posting to https:// pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com  **(yes, there is a space between / and p due to me not being able to post links)**

I get the following error:

```
[RESPMSG] => Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call
[RESULT] => 5
```

Not sure what this is.  According to Paypal Manager, it says:  Status: Your account is currently in ACTIVE status. You can run both live and test transactions.

When using the live checkout, using a real credit card, posting to: https: //payflowlink.paypal.com **(again, I know the space is there)**

I get this response (I took out my information and replaced it with j or whatever):

```
Array
(
    [TYPE] => S
    [STATE] => NV
    [BILLTOEMAIL] => j
    [BILLTOLASTNAME] => j
    [BILLTONAME] => j j
    [LASTNAME] => j
    [PNREF] => E09P2DF86729
    [TENDER] => CC
    [EMAIL] => j
    [PHONE] => 5555555555
    [METHOD] => CC
    [BILLTOFIRSTNAME] => j
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [AMT] => 0.01
    [ZIP] => 99999
    [BILLTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [RESPMSG] => Field format error: Secure Token Not found
    [COUNTRY] => US
    [BILLTOZIP] => j
    [BILLTOCITY] => j
    [TAX] => 0.00
    [BILLTOSTATE] => CA
    [FIRSTNAME] => j
    [AVSDATA] => XXN
    [SECURETOKEN] => QmJyCnGu4X0CEOpHv0eJCGAFV
    [SECURETOKENID] => 1c370788b7cfd3eb23847421918249e8
    [CITY] => j
    [BILLTOPHONE] => 9999999999
    [NAME] => j j
    [BILLTOSTREET] => j
    [COUNTRYTOSHIP] => US
    [RESULT] => 7
    [ADDRESS] => j
)
```

Says Secure Token Not Found, despite, the SECURETOKEN being RIGHT THERE in the response (QmJyCnGu4X0CEOpHv0eJCGAFV).  I have verified that the SECURETOKEN is being sent prior to posting to paypal.

I am not sure where to go from here.

**Edit:  In more testing, if I go through my checkout process, and INSTEAD of directly entering in a Credit Card, I login with one of my sandbox paypal accounts, and pay with a credit card (the same credit card I use to directly pay), it seems to work fine, and i get a RESULT=0.  but the problem seems to lie if I directly pay with a Credit/Debit Card directly on the page.**

Answer (score 1):

To fix the 'Field format error: Secure Token Not found' error log in to PayPal Manager, go to Service Settings, click Set Up, scroll down, and set "Enable Secure Token" to "Yes".